# is there an easy way to have vsftpd server show up again in Webmin 1.530?

Tags: lamp, vsftpd, webmin

VSFTPD is running fine on Ubuntu LAMP server 10.04, but for some reason is no longer available from webmin anymore. Re-installing vsftpd makes no difference. Users are still able to log in via ftp.

Comment: Maybe I should have asked - is there an easy way to have vsftpd server show up again in webmin. Although there is lots of help for configuring vsftpd via it's vsftpd.conf, it would be good to see this add-in working again. Indicating webmin is not boken.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!